# How to show 4 tiles per line on the Surface RT?

Tags: windows, windows-8, start-screen

From these two images, you can see my start screen and then another of the surface rt from a YouTube video.

My surface only shows 3 rows of tiles for some reason but the surface from the YouTube video (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9VYf5MWyTn8) shows 4 rows of tiles.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

How can I modify my start screen to fit 4 rows of tiles?

Comment: You do have the 8.1 update right?  Because they the one from YouTube does have it installed

Comment: 8.1 came Pre-installed with my surface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have Windows RT, however on Windows Pro 8.1, you do this by Win key + C to bring up the Charms, then Settings > Tiles > Show more tiles.